# How to display data on view page

Tags: database, laravel, controller

I cant display my data, laravel's 404 page popping. 
Here is my foreach codes.

```
    @foreach($este as $row) 
      {{$row['価格']}}
      {{$row['間取り']}}
      {{$row['販売戸数']}}
      {{$row['総戸数']}}
      {{$row['専有面積']}}
      {{$row['専有面積']}}
      {{$row['その他面積']}}
      {{$row['所在階/構造 階建']}}
      {{$row['完成時期']}}
      {{$row['住所']}}
    @endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong here.

I want to edit table with css but data doesn't display.

My controller, and route is here:

```
public function sumos()
{
    $este = estates::all();
    return view('pages.sumo', ['este' => $este]);
} 

Route::get("sumo/{id}", "PagesController@sumos");
```

Comment: Your corresponding DB column names are in Japanese too?

Comment: Did you attempt something like `<th>{{$row['価格']}}</th>`  instead? meaning you get the property of that object in array-like way

Comment: You need to show us your error message. Telling us that "error page is pop upping" is not useful in debugging your problem.

Comment: I am getting 404 page right now I add the route sumo/{id} as well

Answer (score 2):

First I wouldn't recommend you to use special characters to name DB columns nor variables, that been said, if you need to access the attribute with a special char you can always provide the variable name as a string like this:

```
{{ $row->{'所在階/構造 階建'} }}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks mate, I think I solved that problem but. My foreach doesnt work. Page is getting error.

Comment: @KubilayTurgut Update your question with the error and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: I update the question mate, can u check it?